# Ios Swift Place Photo with google places sdk

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-places-api

I want to show the first photo of the place with the geo-coordinates from google API but I am not getting any proper way. But what I got is https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/photos now this needs Place-id I am even unable to find place-id with geo-coordinates. Can anyone tell me how can I extract photos of the place with geo-coordinate? Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should first search first for the place with the API.
The response contains an 'placeID', now you can use this ID in your 2nd request.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but is there any way to get the placeID from geo-coordinate? cuz searching is not the option for me.

Comment: Not sure if it's possible, but I think you can do a search for geo-coordinates and that'll response the 'placeID'

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
func loadFirstPhotoForPlace(placeID: String) {
        GMSPlacesClient.shared().lookUpPhotos(forPlaceID: placeID) { (photos, error) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                // TODO: handle the error.
                print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                if let firstPhoto = photos?.results.first {
                    self.loadImageForMetadata(photoMetadata: firstPhoto)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Explain why your code is the answer. add more details as to why this code works rather than just the code.

Comment: And what about All photos of google places how to get all photos of place? GMSPlaceClient only give first and last photo of place.